# Why do I always get 'private key length is invalid' when launching testrpc from java with predefined accounts?

Tags: testrpc, web3j, java

Im trying to deploy testrpc from java with two accounts starting with funds,  and I keep getting an error saying "private key length is invalid" from testrpc. Below is my code:

```
private static final String TESTNETRPC_CMD = "/usr/bin/testrpc"; 
private static final String TESTNETRPC_ARGS = "--account=\"0x%s, 10000000000000000000\"";

private static final String EXCHANGE_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY = "9cfc2211b75dceb15d5ae9d2d7c8c5f5f480d40d1451ff296cd15fe9b7bec422";
private static final String USER_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY     = "41a7ade556eb832ac96bc401f35ff678234643e4d3ecced00e875b66188b1bb4";

ProcessBuilder testnetRpcBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(TESTNETRPC_CMD, String.format(TESTNETRPC_ARGS, EXCHANGE_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY),
            String.format(TESTNETRPC_ARGS, USER_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY));
System.out.println(testnetRpcBuilder.command().toString());
testnetRpcBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
testnetRpc = testnetRpcBuilder.start();
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you share the output of that `println`? Does the same command work if you just type it at the command line?

Comment: Sure, the output is [/usr/bin/testrpc, --account="0x9cfc2211b75dceb15d5ae9d2d7c8c5f5f480d40d1451ff296cd15fe9b7bec422,10000000000000000000", --account="0x41a7ade556eb832ac96bc401f35ff678234643e4d3ecced00e875b66188b1bb4,10000000000000000000"]
If I remove the extra commas and the square brackets, the command works on the command line

Comment: Try double-escaping the quotes: `\\\"` instead of just `\"`. See https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6511002.

Comment: Sorry, that didnt work. That bug seems to be for windows, Im running on linux. I think your right and its definatley something with the parameters. When I run with no arguments it launches testrpc, but no accounts are initialized with funds

Comment: I'd love to make it work with the quotes, but it should work if you just remove them. `TESTNETRPC_ARGS = "--account=0x%s, 100000...";`